# How to use setTimeout with a Loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, use-state

I have a simple functional component where i click a button and it is shown, i am trying to get my imported spinner to show for 2 seconds when the button is clicked and then show my imported component after the two seconds, however i am only able to get the spinner to show 2 seconds after the button is clicked and cannot get it to stop

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner'
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const helloHandeler = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(!loading)
    }, 2000)
    setShow(!show);
  };

  if (loading) return <Spinner />

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Adding a Spinner</h1>
      <div className="bodyContainer">
        {!show && <button onClick={helloHandeler}>Click me</button>}
        {show && <Hello />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-engelbart-y3jus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you trigger `helloHandeler()` it is registering the `setTimeout()` to start only after two seconds! This is the behaviour of `setTimeout()`.

Instead, you should `setLoading()` imediatly, and then `setTimeout` to stop loading 2sec after. Maybe you would want to `setShow()` after the two sec also, so place it inside the `setTimeout()`.

*update*

Also, remmember that JS works asynchronusly, so, when you register setTimeout, the `loading` is not `true` yet.

```
  const helloHandeler = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false)
    setShow(!show);
    }, 2000)

  };
```

Comment: ahhh perfect thank you, however it's then stuck in the infinite loop and doesn't stop after the two seconds, any idea on that?

Comment: Huum... Maybe this: `const helloHandeler = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false)
    setShow(!show);
    }, 2000)
  };`

Comment: you have to clear the timer. Hint: ```clearInterval```

Comment: No, because he didn't used `setInterval()`, it was `setTimeout()`, witch works different! Try the last update...

Answer (score 3):

You can add `useEffect` hook to update the DOM.

You are only updating the `loading` flag inside handler. React does not know that it needs to update the DOM.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (loading) {
    setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 2000);
  }
}, [loading]);
```

Forked codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-liskov-t53fv